# Add three y axis using Altair in Python

Tags: python, plot, altair

I am trying to add the third y axis to the altair plots
It's easy to do this with just two y axis.

```
base = alt.Chart(df).encode(alt.X('time'))

a = base.mark_line(opacity=0.6).encode(alt.Y('price'), color='green')
b = base.mark_point(opacity=0.6).encode(alt.Y('markout'), color='blue')
c = alt.layer(a, b).resolve_scale(y='independent')
```

But if I use this method adding the third y axis

```
c = base.mark_line(opacity=0.6).encode(alt.Y('size'), color='lightgrey')
d = alt.layer(a,b,c).resolve_scale(y='independent')
```

The y axis will overlay on the right.
[image]

Is there a way to add the third axis on the right of the second? Something like this
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can offset [the axis](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/core/altair.Axis.html#altair.Axis) for the third plot. [For example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABMoZJBhpAA8aEQ7CTrMCu+rhJMcZYaYBPQxDhsGlkyQx8AcltoMzhDVxlBBh05Q0w2QwADAB0QYNUcOFlVWUwcjMUQAHcaZXo0ABYABkaleBoyLDQAZmalZXcUVFAGdUE0FQGCSrd6OHVKKAhiEABfJUx1JFkIADM2dQQ0AG1QHZpBD3Vx-swGBEpBNih3XUMAXjfDHIBlGcxBOA5VYAXSUhSgbGUwTIaFAllhIB0CDgAFVZHRxgg5HUlGc4IJlNd3HAKlYbAi9gd3OMAKRMCo6f4k1CyBiCQQrTlKQRIHxzY6gZDqADWCLYOCQUDoPjQjUoXXWPgK4wcbgqEMeV3QAGIABxiADCYn0ADZVmDZBCoSEETKhiAkGQyK4KB4VaRNmQSbiaPjCegPAgcAB9ZDwpTRAEI5RsZDBY4tHrAtaIuhRgzEMiUQwAFUQBU2t1chgAFAAGg0ASlJ1ggCMZAINbE14z1huNZq5IB8ACYEY7nXw3egkB7Hd6QHiCeNAyGEPHOWtBQ5RfaIBs2MLmSA2-oAJxGhlK7fCWQT4KXHDN4mYuRsNJn80gcGQ6G2-tOl03kdjr0VKf+iAOCuFKOB0C8cgMmm24AAogVo4HJLIpbBLAajVkoZJ1vaDZwE2LY6vq+6HouS4gEKq6gOu6ibtuu4HmIR7Kugp7niUcxXjyw7kXeD4kimL7WjC9p2qAA5ftxo5zOO-6+tOAb5qG8brNB4x5kG0lFrE87yJhtb1tB+H7K2REMRUbA7DsASYGgYiNKRoIgPEzakAikbMqAdq5EUcAFD5JSrJyQA)

```py
c = (
    base.mark_line(opacity=0.6)
    .encode(
        alt.Y('size', axis=alt.Axis(offset=40)), 
        color='lightgrey'
    )
)
```